# cannot display the morris.js chart with expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, morris.js

I work with expressJS, Handlebars like template engine and MongoDB, I want to display a graph on my web page with morris.js using this code in my index.hbs file

```
<script  id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

     console.log("fooooo")
    new Morris.Line({
      // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
      element: 'myfirstchart',
      // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
      // the chart.
      data: {{graph}},
      // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
      xkey: 'version',
      // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
      ykeys: ['success'],
      // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
      // chart.
      labels: ['success']
    });

   </script>
    <div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

but nothing is displayed (even the log)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should put your script code below in `document ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
new Morris.Line({
      // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
      element: 'myfirstchart',
      // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
      // the chart.
      data: {{graph}},
      // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
      xkey: 'version',
      // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
      ykeys: ['success'],
      // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
      // chart.
      labels: ['success']
    });
})
```

Comment: same thing..no thing is displayed, it's like my template engine does not read the JS code into the script tag

Comment: if there is no error from console, you should check your "{{graph}}". It may constain wrong data format !

Comment: I checked, it's correct, I said even the log does not appear in my console, I guess the problem is with the use of JavaScript inside handlebars.js template

Comment: the layout.hbs?

Comment: show me the script code on your HTML display on web browser,

Comment: Please expand your script tag ("entry-template")! ^^